# How to save SystemC variables during vcs simulation and restore back based on stimulus change

Tags: system-calls

My tests are in SystemC env and for all my tests i run a common routine(basically its my init sequence which doesn't vary much based on seed). This common routine is followed by my actual test.

## It looks something like this:

Test_MAIN 
`init_seq();`

## `my_test();`;

Here init_seq() is that common routine and my_test() is my actual test that have actual test sequence which initiate multiple SC threads, for initiating various kind of traffic.

Now, my problem is that i want a way to avoid init_seq() for every run. The entire test should run for one time and the next time i should have a mechanism to directly run from my_test()(which is basically skipping/preloading init_seq() part to the simulator).

VCS save and restore can't be used directly as in this case we also will have to restore the SystemC variables.

Could you please direct me on this..!!

Thanks
ByreddyNaresh

Answer (score 1):

I tried with a SystemC test with init() and run() routine, and use VCS save/restart to restore the test. It seems OK to me that a member variable 'cnt' in test is restored successfully.

This is my test:

```
// test.h

#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

#include <systemc.h>

class test: public sc_module{

public:
    sc_in<bool> init_start;
    sc_in<bool> run_start;

    void init();
    void run();

    int cnt;

    SC_CTOR(test){

    SC_THREAD(init);
    sensitive_pos << init_start;
    dont_initialize();

    SC_THREAD(run);
    sensitive_pos << run_start;
    dont_initialize();
    }

};

#endif
```

and

```
// test.cpp

#include "test.h"

void test::init(){
    printf("test init:\n");
    while(1){
        cnt = 10;
        printf("init cnt to %d\n", cnt);
        wait();
    }
}


void test::run(){
    printf("test run:\n");
    while(1){
        cnt++;
        printf("cnt = %d\n", cnt);
        wait();
    }
}
```

and the top:

```
// tb.v

module tb;

reg init_start;
reg run_start;

initial begin
init_start = 0;
run_start = 0;
#100
init_start = 1;
#100
$save("save.chk");
#100
run_start = 1;
#100
$finish;
end


test u_test(
.init_start(init_start),
.run_start(run_start)
);

endmodule
```

After 'save.chk' is generated, I run it directly and the output is:

```
$ save.chk
Chronologic VCS simulator copyright 1991-2012
Contains Synopsys proprietary information.
Compiler version G-2012.09; Runtime version G-2012.09;  Mar  5 18:01 2014
test run:
cnt = 11
$finish called from file "tb.v", line 17.
$finish at simulation time                 1300
           V C S   S i m u l a t i o n   R e p o r t 
Time: 1300 ps
CPU Time:      0.260 seconds;       Data structure size:   0.0Mb
Wed Mar  5 18:01:08 2014
```

It seems variable 'cnt' is restored from '10', as is done in init() routine.

Don't know if this is the case you met?